# How Do I Encode/Decode Webp Format in Memory using Opencv on Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to load 90,000 images in `webp` format in memory, and decode as needed for speed.
However, I can't get the following test code to decode the encoded format.
I'd appreciate any pointer.

```py
img = cv2.imread(file)
retval, buf = cv2.imencode(".webp", img, [cv2.IMWRITE_WEBP_QUALITY, 100])
img = cv2.imdecode(buf, 1)
```

> imdecode_(''): can't read data: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_webp.cpp:164: error: (-215:Assertion failed) data.rows == 1 in function 'readData'

Answer (score 2):

According to the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html), you should do:

```
retval, buf = cv2.imencode(".webp", 
                           img, 
                           [cv2.IMWRITE_WEBP_QUALITY, 100])

img = cv2.imdecode(buf, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but got a different error. `retval, buf = cv2.imencode(".webp", img, [cv2.IMWRITE_WEBP_QUALITY, 100])` `img = cv2.imdecode(buf, 1)` now gives imdecode_(''): can't read data: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_webp.cpp:164: error: (-215:Assertion failed) data.rows == 1 in function 'readData'

Comment: I figure there must be a flag indicating image size and format when use `imdecode`. But I can't find reference anywhere.

Comment: The type and dimensions are in the WEBP-encoded buffer. Just change the second line to `numpyarray = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(buf,dtype=np.uint8),1)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell it doesn't work on opencv 3.4. Still return `None`

Comment: @MarkSetchell `cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(buf,dtype=np.uint8),1)` gives imdecode_(''): can't read data: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_webp.cpp:164: error: (-215:Assertion failed) data.rows == 1 in function 'readData' Also `retval, buf = cv2.imencode(".webp", img, [cv2.IMWRITE_WEBP_QUALITY, 100])` already gives numpy. `type(buf)` <class 'numpy.ndarray'> buf.shape [28208, 1)

Comment: That looks like v4.1.0. Not sure what's going on, it certainly works for me on v3.4 but I will experiment some more.

Comment: Thanks, I also confirmed `cv2.imdecode(buf, 1)` works in v3.4.2. Guess need to find out how to make it work in 4.0.

Comment: Interestingly, in 4.1.0, it doesn't even give me an error, and just returns None.

Answer (score 0):

his is OpenCV bug, and it looks like the fix will be included in the future release.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14978

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/14989

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded opencv-python to 4.5.1.48 and solved problem